# no such module 'Firebase' when creating own pod

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to create a new framework called Experiments. It is wrapping Firebase RemoteConfig APIs for any app I may build using it.

When I run the following command `pod lib lint Experiments.podspec`, I get the following output with errors.

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- NOTE...
- NOTE...
.
.
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  <path/to/file>: error: no such module 'Firebase'
```

Here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Experiments' do

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

  target 'ExperimentsTests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Here is a relevant portion of my podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Experiments'
  s.version          = '0.1.3'
  s.summary          = 'This pod allows A/B Testing.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
  This pod facilitates AB Testing. Currently, it is powered by Firebase only.
                       DESC
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE.txt' }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'
  s.source_files = "Experiments/*.{swift}"
  s.swift_version = "5.0"
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'Foundation'
  s.dependency 'Firebase'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
end
```

I was able to successfully build my framework on XCode after `pod install`.

I tried using `s.static_framework = true` in `.podspec` file but I keep getting an error.

Please post a comment if you need clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s.static_framework = true` is required.

There's likely no reason to depend on the `Firebase` pod.

`s.dependency 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'` without the slash is more likely to work.

If you're still seeing errors with these changes, please include them in the question.